# Making a combobox with nested items wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to create a combobox in wpf that has nested items so that each item expands horizontally and I can peek sub items. after selecting a sub item, the combobox text and value should be equal to that sub item . I found [this](http://www.bengribaudo.com/blog/2011/01/21/675/combobox-displaying-a-drop-down-menu) on internet . It looks pretty fine but it doesn't behave how I want . it's just a menu looking like a combo box.

Comment: Can you show please how you have tried the sample you posted for combobox and where are you facing problem?

Comment: @sivaGopal I want to check the box's text and value in my program but it works based on events. the header doesn't change when I choose an item.

Comment: Post some code you created so far, so that someone can help you to fix if not they have to work your task.

Comment: I didn't change it's code . I just used it the way it is and I want to be able to check the text and value of the control every time and it should change when user selects an item. just like a combobox.

Comment: I don't think this is available in core functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing like `SubItems` available in `ComboBox`. You will have to define your own such control. You can also search & get third party control.
I would recommend you using `TreeView`.

Comment: I know the default ComboBox doesn't have something like this, my question is how to make one or where to find one. I searched for days but the only thing I found is the link I shared. TreeView needs a big space and I have only a tiny space for my control. I need something to expand on the top of other controls. something like a ComboBox.